# python in applescript: subprocess.call vs os.system in automator

Tags: python, shell, automator, os.system, subprocess

I found a work around when calling a python script from a shell script from automator (version 2.1.1 in mac os x 10.6.8) (python 2.6.1).  My issue is that os.system("mkdir foo") works in a (very specific) case where subprocess.call("mkdir foo") **also makes the directory** but then makes automator throw an error.

The purpose of my automator app is to accept an image that is dragged-and-dropped onto it.
The automator app has just one action: 'run shell script' with the following code:

```
for f in "$@"
do
    python dphoto_pythons/uploader.py $f > dphoto_pythons/auto_output.txt
done
```

$f is the name of the dragged image. ('Run shell script' is set to pass input as arguments.)
Here is the strange part:

in the 'uploader.py' script, I was calling this:

```
retcode=call("mkdir " + dir_full, shell=True) # THIS CAUSES A ERROR IN AUTOMATOR
print "***DOESN'T GET HERE WHEN RUN IN AUTOMATOR****"
```

It makes the directory. but doesn't get to the next statement. And automator would throw up an error dialog (which just says that I should go check my script).

By contrast, if I called uploader.py 'manually' from the terminal:

```
"python uploader.py someimage.jpg"
```

it worked without a hitch.
After puzzling over this for a bit, I tried replacing call with os.system:

```
os.system("mkdir " + stu_dir_full)
####retcode=call("mkdir " + stu_dir_full, shell=True) #  BUG
```

This works from automator and from terminal.
I have a feeling that I'm over-looking something obvious because this is such a bizarre problem.  But thought I'd put this out there in any case.  Any thoughts?

-Mel

Comment: Use the Console.app in /Applications/Utilites to check your system logs; chances are the relevant error messages are there.  But why make it so complicated?  Use the built-in Python library function "os.mkdir()" http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.mkdir

Comment: Why in the world would you shell out just to make a directory?

Answer (score 0):

You could use os.mkdir(stu_dir_full)...

But the problem with your subprocess.call line might be that subprocess.call is expecting a list not a string. Try this:

```
retcode = call(["mkdir",dir_full], shell=True)
```